# asp.net membership comparing current logged on user password change and creation dates

Tags: asp.net, membership

```
protected void Login2_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Membership.GetUser().LastPasswordChangedDate == Membership.GetUser().CreationDate)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx");
    }
}
```

As you can see im wanting to force password changes on the first login. however i am not doing it correctly. The examples that I tried to use appear to have built their own login controls. I am using the built in login control so i'm not sure how to get a handle to the text boxes it uses.

The error that I am getting on the if statement is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Seems the `GetUser()` method returns NULL, when do you call this method? after login or before it?

Comment: on the loggedin event, so i believe it to be after.

Comment: Check first the `HttpContext.Current.Identity` and make sure the `User` is not null, maybe you have not set it correctly

Comment: system.web.httpcontext does not contain a definition for identity, it tells me

Comment: It is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity'